# Hosting my own Google Analytics solution

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, bug-tracking, event-tracking

I want to collect, store et report tracking datas (like used features, clicked buttons, ...) using javascript library and .net API. I know Google Analytics will be perfect for this. But my direction doesn't want to use it for privacy and security reasons. So i have to develop one or use an all-in-one package (piwik maybe).

Do you have any tips for me ?

Thanks

Comment: I upvoted the downvote , why downvote? This is a good question from the OP

Comment: @Jelman, this is not a question about a specific programming problem as described in the help center, so I'd say it is off-topic (which probably warrents a close vote rather than a downvote). Inasfar as the OP is asking for a software recommendation there is an extra stackexchange site for this.

Comment: Ok @EikePierstorff you have a point there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ID's these are allowed to use as long as google cannot identify the user behind it, so a system which uses the id's in GA to obtain more information about a user can be very useful solution.

Since your direction does not want to use GA you could create it yourself.
It has been done at my company for certain situations.

I will not do your homework but the concept of it is :

Send calls to a homemade webservice (json format is pretty good for this),
create the service so it can interpret the json and put the raw data in a temporary Database. Do data checks , merges with backend data and possible conversions and store everything in a database from where you will make your reports.

Comment: I can't use GA at all, direction want to store its own datas

Comment: What "ID's" are you talking about ? what is ? 
Maybe I don't think about the same thing

Comment: If you track users, you always have some kind of ID to recognise the fact user.. if you don't have this it's impossible to differentiate 2 different users.. Weather it's a login-id or a generated id by google or yourself, you can not speak about users if you do not have an id.

Comment: Ok I did not know. How do I retrieve this ID from google ? with an api or a library ?

Comment: The google ID is not interesting in your situation since you won't use GA, can you describe your website , what it does , are your users logged in all the time? etc.. etc..

Comment: But regarding your question you don't want to use the term users,  you just want numbers of how many times an event has occured is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's right, but knowing how to get a GoogleId is for my personal enrichment ;)


For the work i'm always searching a simply ready made solution. It's for a mobile website used by PDA

Comment: Allright, I always add the userid from our registration system as a custom dimension.

Comment: In your situation if the only thing you need to know is the amount of eventclicks and some additional data and you can't use a premade tool that won't hold personal data and stuff, I would recommend to write your own webservice and push the info to a database.

If my answer solved your problem feel free to accept.

If more questions, shoot